React dynamically fill the select component and pic one selected value on form submit
using hook forms, I want to submit form data with a select option for department and these department filled dynamically from the server
I have a select component with is picking my selected values very well but when I submit the data, the selected component value is not showing up

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can You share more about the data that is passed to this select component. If while submitting the data, the value is not showing up then it means that the component is not working as expected. Make sure that the data passed to that component is in correct format. Usually the format is like this,
const data = [
    {label: 'Dog', value: 0}
    {label: 'Cat', value: 1}
]

The label is shown at the frontend and value is picked from the option whenever the select is changed. Make sure you are doing it correctly

#This is example of options am sending to the select option
const category =['Backend','Frontend','Fullstack'];
#this is my interface to ceive diffrent types of option
`interface Props {
Option: string[];
onChange:(Options:string)=>void;}
const SelectOption = ({Option,onChange}:Props) => {
return
#This is my select componet
<select onChange={(event)=>onChange(event.target.value)} className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
All Categories
{Option.map((item)=>({item}))}
`